# Is it possible to render Swagger UI from swagger YAML file in ReadeMe.md file ? just to display UI once Commit code in github

Tags: swagger, markdown

Is there any way to visualize swagger YAML file inside ReadeMe.md. Only way I can put file
`[Swagger Codegen](/assets/swagger.yaml)`

my structure for codebase is

```
Project
  src
  assets
     swagger.yaml
  ReadeMe.md
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try convert the `swagger.yaml` to markdown, then put it in readme.

Conversion tools like: https://github.com/syroegkin/swagger-markdown

There's a online demo here: https://swagger-markdown-ui.netlify.app/